# Write a function to determine the minimum number of times the original sorted list was rotated to obtain the given list. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: python, list, rotation, binary-search

Example: The list [5, 6, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4] was obtained by rotating the sorted list [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9] 3 times.

here is my code -

```py
def count_rotations_binary(nums):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(nums)-1
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        mid_number = nums[mid]
        print("lo:", lo, ", hi:", hi, ", mid:", mid, ", mid_number:", mid_number)
    if mid > 0 and nums[mid] < nums[mid-1]  :
            # The middle position is the answer
        return mid
    elif nums[mid] < nums[len(nums)-1] :
            # Answer lies in the left half
        hi = mid - 1  
    else:
            # Answer lies in the right half
        lo = mid + 1
    return 0
q = count_rotations_binary([9,10,11,1,4,6,7,8])
print(q)
```

Comment: Can you make sure the indentation of the code is correct?

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure that it is

Comment: isn't the answer always going to be just `nums.index(min(nums))`?  Binary search seems overkill unless you expect the list to be really huge.

Comment: @Samwise the caveat is that I got to use a searching algorithm  and it's got to  be the optimal solution

Comment: If you want all your code to be inside the `while` loop, it needs to be indented.  If you fix that and remove the mysterious `return 0` it seems to work fine.